# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS - VS Emulator for Android

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-emulator

I have a Cordova app that I'm trying to run on VS Emulator for Android.

I start the emulator in advance from the GUI:

[image]

Running `cordova run android` errors out with:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`

Comment: Could you please try with an empty blank project?

Comment: Hmm - blank project works fine.